# Erro em código teste: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python

Eu fiz um código teste, mas não sei qual o erro, alguém me ajuda?

```
class Caneta:
    def _init_(self, cor, modelo, ponta):
        self._cor = cor
        self._modelo = modelo
        self._ponta = ponta
        self._carga = 100
        self._tampada = True
    def _getCor(self):
        return self._cor
    def _getModelo(self):
        return self._modelo
    def _getPonta(self):
        return self._ponta
    def _getCarga(self):
        return self._carga
    def _isTampada(self):
        return self._tampada
    def _setCor(self, cor):
        self._cor = cor
    def _setModelo(self, modelo):
        self._modelo = modelo
    def _setPonta(self, ponta):
        self._ponta = ponta
    def _setCarga(self, carga):
        self._carga = carga
    def _setTampada(self, tampada):
        self._tampada = tampada
    def tampar(self):
        if(not self._isTampada):
            setTampada(True)
            print("Caneta tampada com sucesso")
        else:
            print("A caneta ja esta tampada")
    def destampar(self):
        if(self._isTampada):
            setTampada("False")
            print("Caneta destampada com sucesso")
        else:
            print("A caneta ja esta destampada")
    def recarregar(self):
        if(getCarga() < 100):
            print("Caneta recarregada de {} para 100 com sucesso.".format(str(getCarga())))
            setCarga(100)
        else:
            print("A caneta esta cheia.")
    def escrever(self, msg):
        if(getCarga()>=(getCarga()-len(msg)/2) and msg!=null and self._isTampada):
            print(msg)
            self._carga-=len(msg) / 2
    def status(self):
        print("Cor:{}\nModelo:{}\nPonta:{}\nCarga:{}\nTampada:{}".format(self._cor, self._modelo, str(self._ponta), str(self._carga), str(self._tampada)))
c = Caneta("Azul", "Bic", 0.5)
c.status()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O metodo init está escrito errado, a maneira correta de escreve-lo seria com dois underlines, da seguinte maneira:

```
class Caneta:
  def __init__(self, cor, modelo, ponta):
    self._cor = cor
    self._modelo = modelo
    self._ponta = ponta
    self._carga = 100
    self._tampada = True
```

Realizei um teste e rodou normalmente após a correção.